# Rails_admin custom field to edit hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

My app is Rails 4.1.14, rails_admin 0.8.1 and mongoid 5.  I used this https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1218 as a guide to create custom fields to edit arrays.  It works great by splitting input by coma and saving it as array.

I also have several Hash fields with fairly specific structure.  Rails_admin shows them as strings allowing to edit as textarea which is very error prone.

Does anyone have expereince building custom fields for editing hashes?  Would I need to create a partial and load it for each field?

Comment: I know it's not a great solution, but what I've done is to add attr_accesor on the model for those fields I want on the hash and then joining them into a hash in a before_save hook.